# How does Windows Phone consume cellular data?

Tags: wifi, cellular

I wonder how is my data used when I'm not on the wifi?
Am I avaliable on FB, does my email check ferquently?

I don't want to consume my internet for non-sense like FB and E-mails until I go into app and click "check my email".
But still I want to use internet for my apps which are running as background agents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option to select what to use on what connection. when you enable your cellular data connection it is used for all apps you have selected to be online. being it mail sync, facebook chat or background agents of apps.

for example your mail will keep syncing if you're not on wifi. same for facebook connection you'll stay online when you are on 3g instead of wifi. Wifi will also be turned off automatically if your phone screen is turned of to save battery so you'll switch to cellular then.

The only option is to set syncing your mail to manual and put facebook on ofline when you are not using it.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for :)