# Why does it take so long for the phone fall back to WIFI when I have weak GPRS/3G?

Tags: wifi, cellular-data

When I'm at home I have a really bad data signal. I barely get standard GPRS signal... No EDGE or HSPDA. But I have a WIFI router 5 meters from where I sit with my phone and laptop. My laptop have full signal strength to the WIFI net, so I guess my phone has that too.

When I try to access anything from the net on my phone it takes a really long time before it starts downloading the site/file/data. When it at last starts to download the data it goes really fast (WIFI speed). If I'm at my brothers place, which have the same kind of router, I have full HSPDA connection and it starts downloading at once. But much faster then it would through HSPDA. So I'm quite sure it downloads through the WIFI connection. Also If I manually turn of my data connection it starts loading data directly.

It's like it first trying against the data connection before it falls back on the WIFI connection.

Is this how Windows Phone works? Or can I change this somehow? It's really annoying that I have to wait for 20-30 seconds before it starts loading the webpage I've navigated to... And when it at last starts it finish in just a second or so. And manually turning of my data connection each time I come home seems like a pretty crud workaround.

I read these threads:

[Does Windows Phone prioritize between using a data plan and wi-fi connection?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/91/does-windows-phone-prioritize-between-using-a-data-plan-and-wi-fi-connection)

[How does Windows Phone consume cellular data?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/210/how-does-windows-phone-consume-cellular-data)

[How can I tell whether I'm getting data via Wi-Fi or phone network?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/425/how-can-i-tell-whether-im-getting-data-via-wi-fi-or-phone-network?lq=1)

But non of them really answered my question.

Edit: My phone is a Samsung Omnia W
(thanks for noticing that I forgot to mention that... :) )

Comment: Perhaps mention the model of your phone. My Lumia 800 seems to connected almost instantly to my WiFi when at home.

Comment: A.. yes... of course. It's a Samsung Omnia W.  Do your Lumia connect instantly even if you have a really weak gprs/3g connection? My problem only appears (as I write in the question) when I have a really weak signal. When I have a good signal there is no problem.

Comment: My Lumia 800 connects very quickly to WiFi when there is a poor celular connection. I tested in my concrete bomb shelter where the HSDPA reception ranged from 0-2 bars and turned WiFi off. It connected very quickly after turning WiFi on. Turning the screen off while in Twitter and then turning it back on resulted in almost instantaneous WiFi reconnection.

Comment: It sounds to me like the Omnia W has issues. A quick search seems to show other people also [having issues](http://forums.wpcentral.com/focus-flash-4g-omnia-w/184405.htm) with the Omnia W and WiFi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue and it is very annoying. I believe it's a firmware issue as I didn't have the problem with the original firmware - it started after a firmware update. For now I have only Wi-Fi activated and then I have to switch manually to data connection if I have no Wi-Fi within range. I so much hope there will be a new firmware update that solves this issue ... :-( The phone is otherwise very nice and Windows Phone 7.5 is excellent.

Comment: This, unfortunately, seems to be the correct answer. Well well. I either just have to get a Lumia instead... or wait for WP8 phones to hit the shelves.